# Why does Artifactory have both Gradle and Maven repositories?

Tags: artifactory

After evaluating Artifactory for the first time, I find it confusing that when going through the initial setup, and selecting both Maven and Gradle integration, it creates two sets of repositories for me

1. platform-gradle-dev-local
2. platform-gradle-release-local
3. platform-libs-release-local
4. platform-libs-snapshot-local

While I have used Maven for many years, I am new to Gradle. The mystery to me is, I cannot see any utility in having separate repos for Gradle and Maven builds, and I cannot fathom from JFrog documentation why they do this.

**Is there any reason to use the two gradle repos, or can I just use the standard Maven repos for all builds? Gradle, Maven, SBT, etc.**

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory Gradle repositories have a different layout than Maven repositories.
The layout used for Gradle repositories is compatible with the one use by the default Gradle Ivy [repository layout](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:ivy_repositories).
Unless you need to use this repository layout, you should be perfectly fine working with a Maven repository.